# Почему параллельная сортировка медленнее обычной?

Tags: java, производительность, java-stream

В чём подвох, почему параллельная сортировка медленнее обычной?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main().f();
    }

    void f() throws Exception {
        int sz = (int) Math.pow(10, 7);
        int[] a = new Random().ints(sz, 0, 10000).toArray();
        int[] a1 = a.clone();
        int[] a2 = a.clone();

        long time1 = calcTime(() -> streamSort(a1));
        long time2 = calcTime(() -> parallelStreamSort(a2));

        System.out.println(time1);
        System.out.println(time2);
    }

    List<Integer> streamSort(int[] a) {
        return Arrays.stream(a).sorted().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    List<Integer> parallelStreamSort(int[] a) {
        return Arrays.stream(a).parallel().sorted().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    long calcTime(Worker worker) throws Exception {
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        worker.doWork();
        return Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis();
    }

    public interface Worker {
        void doWork() throws Exception;
    }
}
```

Comment: Здесь, похоже, не вызывается именно параллельная сортировка. [Тут](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/java-8-parallel-arrays-example/) сказано, что параллельную сортировку реализует `parallelSort()`, а в коде обычная.

Comment: @Vesper в коде тоже параллельная: `parallel().sorted()`. Как вариант тоже подходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

И какие у вас получились цифры?
У меня выдало:

4041

1064

То есть параллельная сортировка вышла быстрее в 4 раза примерно.

Вообще, ваши результаты будут зависеть от многих факторов:

- количество процессоров и ядер процессора на вашей системе
- загруженность процессоров в момент времени запуска программы
- количество элементов в вашем стриме
- стоимость операции над отдельным элементом стрима (а некоторые операции вообще плохо распараллеливаются)

Дело в том, что параллельная сортировка будет давать прирост только в том случае, если накладные расходы на создание потоков будут меньше, чем выигрыш от распараллеливания. Если ваша система нагружена другой работой, то несколько потоков могут тормозить тест, а не ускорять его. То же самое касается небольших стримов: для них затраты на создание дополнительных потоков могут оказаться выше, чем выигрыш от распараллеливания.

Ну и по самому бенчмарку есть замечания:

Мерять производительность подобным образом неправильно. Для этого существуют специальные инструменты, как, например, официальный тул для Java-бенчмаркинга [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Comment: Спасибо за этот тул для бенчмаркинга, буду тестировать.
А вообще сначала у меня выдавало результаты раза в два-три хуже в распараллеленном виде по сравнению с обычным, поэтому решил спросить.
Чем-то в то время все потоки были заняты видимо, но сейчас и я вижу прирост в скорости, хоть и не всегда.

Comment: @PloadyFree это может зависеть даже от вашей ОС, параметров, с которыми вы запускаете JVM, работы сборщика мусора и кучи других параметров. для более подробного ознакомления со Stream, ForkJoinPool (который лежит в основе параллельности стримов), бенчмаркингом в Java я бы посоветовал посмотреть видео докладов от Алексея Шипилёва и Сергея Куксенко

Comment: Все их видео смотрел. Именно после их докладов (коих я видел два - до выхода Java8 и после) я попробовал стримы. Удивительная вещь, добился в своём универе (занимаюсь спортивным программированием, сам в этом году только поступаю на 1 курс) того, чтобы Java7 поменяли на Java8 ради лямбд и стримов, очень уж всё красиво и быстро работает. Неделю назад сдал OCAJP8, а для OCPJP необходимо знание ForkJoin фреймворка, поэтому до него я совсем скоро доберусь. Книжки Хорстанна очень помогают. А вообще явой я начал заниматься только полгода назад, но уж очень она увлекательная.